# How to add alias column in SQL Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some assistance.

I have pursed the City name from the purchase address with the alias "City" .

Now I have a I have a problem statement saying "Find the top cities with the highest sales".

Now, the city column is not into the main table so I cannot run a group by operation. How would I perform this task?

[image: Here is the pic of my tables]

Comment: Move your expression into a CROSS APPLY

Comment: both are in same table. How would I do it?

Comment: Also, posting images is not helpful.

Comment: Remove those `BEGIN TRANSACTION` lines - you’re only doing queries, not DML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to get the city with the highest number of Quantity_Ordered, you can try this.

Since your `data` table doesn't contain the city exactly but it needs to be parsed, it would probably be best to create a view.

```
CREATE VIEW vProductDataCity AS
SELECT *, PARSENAME... -- Fill the "..." with your parsing code
```

And then to get the top city:

```
SELECT TOP(1) city, SUM(Quantity_Ordered) as SumQuantity_Ordered
FROM vProductDataCity
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY SumQuantity_Ordered DESC;
```

Comment: The right idea, you just forgot DESC in the Order By

Comment: Or just a straight sub-query if it's a one time use which doesn't justify a view.

Comment: @DaleK Could you please let me know the sub-query?

Comment: As per any sub-query, instead of `FROM vProductDataCity` you have `FROM (SELECT *, PARSENAME... FROM vProductDataCity) AS AnyAlias`.